# Get data from emitted value

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the values of the data parameter from an emmitted value in my second component

Here is my code

*Component 1 TS*

```
this.myService.emitChange({emitValue: 'openFunctionInSidePanel',  data: data });
```

*Component 2 Service file*

```
private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();
changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

emitChange(event) {
  this.emitChangeSource.next(event);
}
```

Component 2 TS

```
console.log(this.myService.emitChange);
```

So how would I get the actual data value in my component 2.ts file?

I currently see

```
ƒ (event) {
        this.emitChangeSource.next(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "subscribe" to changeEmitted$.

You can do in ngOnInit

```
//don't forget unsubscribe!!!
ngOnInit()
{
    this.myService.changeEmitted$.subscribe((res:any)=>{
         console.log(res)
    })
}
```

Or if only want to show the result you can use [pipe async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

You can declare as public the service in constructor

```
constructor(public myService:MyService){}

//in html
<div *ngIf="myService.changeEmitted$|async as value">
  {{value.emitValue}} - {{value.data|json}}
</div>
```

Or declare as private and use an auxiliar variable

```
changeService$=this.myService.changeEmitted$

constructor(private myService:MyService){}

//in html
<div *ngIf="changeService$|async as value">
   {{value.emitValue}} - {{value.data|json}}
</div>
```

NOTE: you can also "play" with rxjs operators for,e.g. filter the response and transform to only return the "data"

```
changeService$=this.myService.changeEmitted$.pipe(
   filter((res:any)=>res.emitValue=='openFunctionInSidePanel'),
   map((res:any)=>res.data)
)

//then subscribe to this.changeService or use in .html `{{changeService|async}}`
```

NOTE: I add a response because the article indicate in the another answer don't take account the async pipe

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there should be a shared service between the 2 components. Emit the value from component 1 using the service and subscribe to the value from component 2 using the shared service.

Refer to the 4th method of this [article](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angular/sharing-data-between-angular-components-methods) which shows how to pass data between unrelated components.